# Optimization tips for a cuda code

Tags: c++, matlab, cuda, gpu

I wrote a piece of code for computing Self Quotient Image (SQI) in MATLAB. And now i want to rewrite a part of it in parallel for speedup.
this part of code is:

```
siz=15;
X=normalize8(X);
[a,b]=size(X);
filt = fspecial('gaussian',[siz siz],sigma);
padsize = floor(siz/2);
padX = padarray(X,[padsize, padsize],'symmetric','both');

t0 = tic; % -------------------------------------------------------------
Z=zeros(a,b);
for i=padsize+1:a+padsize
    for j=padsize+1:b+padsize
        region = padX(i-padsize:i+padsize, j-padsize:j+padsize);
        means= mean(region(:));
        M=return_step(region, means);
        filt1=filt.*M;

        summ=sum(sum(filt1));        

        filt1=(filt1/summ);
        Z(i-padsize,j-padsize)=(sum(sum(filt1.*region))/(siz*siz));
    end
end
toc(t0) % -------------------------------------------------------------
```

and return_step function:

```
function M=return_step(X, means)

[a,b]=size(X);
for i=1:a
    for j=1:b
        if X(i,j)>=means
            M(i,j)=1;
        end
    end
end
```

I wrote below kernel function:

```
__global__ void returnstep(const double* x, double* m, double* filt, int leng, double mean, int i, int j, int width)
{
    int idx=threadIdx.y*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    if(idx>=leng) return;

    int ridx= (j+threadIdx.y)*width+threadIdx.x+i;
    double xval= x[ridx];
    if (xval>=mean) m[idx]=filt[idx]*xval;
    else            m[idx]=0;
}
```

and then changed the MATLAB code as follow:

```
kernel= parallel.gpu.CUDAKernel('returnstep.ptx', 'returnstep.cu');
kernel.ThreadBlockSize= [double(siz) double(siz) 1];
GM = gpuArray(zeros(siz,siz));
GpadX = gpuArray(padX);
Gfilt = gpuArray(filt);

%% Process image
t0 = tic; % -------------------------------------------------------------
Z=zeros(a,b);
for i=padsize+1:a+padsize
    for j=padsize+1:b+padsize
        means= mean(region(:));
        GM= feval(kernel, GpadX, GM, Gfilt, siz*siz, means, i-padsize-1, j-padsize-1, padXwidth);
        filt1=  gather(GM);

        summ=sum(sum(filt1));        

        filt1=(filt1/summ);
        Z(i-padsize,j-padsize)=(sum(sum(filt1))/(siz*siz));
    end
end
toc(t0) % -------------------------------------------------------------
```

my sequential code runs in 2.5s for a 330X200 image but the new parallel code's run time is 15s. I don't know why????
I need some advise for improving it. I am new in CUDA programming.

Comment: Double precision is very inefficient on most CUDA-capable GPUs, since DP instructions get serialized - can you use single precision ?

Comment: Yes, i tested single precision too, but the result did not change!

Comment: Another bottleneck can be the if statement. Try instead to avoid the if and just write M(i,j)=M(i,j)+X(i,j)>=means  etc... On a different note, instead of that nested for loop, can't you just write: function M=return_step(X, means)
M(find(X>=means))=1; ?

Comment: I think your tips are for sequential code, right?

Comment: Please try moving the `if (xval>=mean)` from your kernel to the host side. In CUDA a warp of threads (typically 32 threads) work in parallel, if one of the 32 threads do not satisfy the `if`, the others get stalled. Try to put only the `m[idx]=filt[idx]*xval` in your kernel, and removing the conditionals out of it. Also, using the CUDA profiler might be beneficial, since you would get hints and graphical cues as to where your code might go wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> help gather
...
X = GATHER(A) when A is a GPUArray, X is an array in the local workspace
with the data transferred from the GPU device.
....
```

filt1 = gather(GM) is copying GM from the GPU to the CPU in every step, which is very inefficient. You should move the entire computation inside the loop nest, or preferably the entire loop nest to the GPU kernel. Otherwise you can forget about any speedup.

Comment: I removed the ghater line but the run time only decreased 5 second! how can you explain 10s run time for cuda code?

Comment: What is the size of your problem? if you start the CUDA kernel in a loop you will every time pay the cost of kernel startup. If your problem size is too small, you will not benefit from parallelism for two reasons 1) GPU is most efficient if all or most of its threads are working, i.e. occupancy is close to 1. and 2) startup overhead will dominate. And really, it is better to put the entire nest loop into the kernel.

Comment: Those are of course just general ideas. You can have look at the following papers for a very good summary of efficient GPU programing guidelines. V. Volkov, J. W. Demmel, Benchmarking gpus to tune dense linear algebra, X. Cui, Y. Chen, H. Mei, Improving performance of matrix multiplication and fft on gpu, J. M. Cohen, J. Molemake, A fast double precision cfd code using cuda,

Answer (score 0):

My evaluation under Sobel filter shows the CPU outperforms GPU on small images. I think your image size is so small for comparison of CPU-GPU performance. Computation should be large enough to hide kernel and communication launch overhead.

Comment: I don't agree with you. because when i implemented the whole loops on GPU, I got up to 30X speedup.